# OrientDB: How to get a list of children from an ODocument (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, orientdb, document-database

In Scala, if one has an [ODocument](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Document-Database) object from querying an OrientDB database, how does one deserialize one of the document's fields that contains a list of child objects?

Consider the following (Scala) method that receives an ODocument and accesses the document's field "versions":

```
def document2package(doc: ODocument) = {
  val versions: String = doc.field("versions")
  // How to make versions into a Seq[Version]?
}
```

The "versions" field is actually a list of `Version` objects, but gets returned as a `String`. How do we deserialize this list?

Comment: Can you check which type is received? Perhaps it is already a List or Vector?..

Comment: @Ashalynd It seems to be a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just cast the result field as `OTrackedList[*Something*]` if you saved the document field as array. It seems to be automatically deserialized if `*Something*` implements `OSerializableStream`.

The following code is the example that seems to work in Orient-DB 1.6.4.

However if you inserted the "list of Version" as String when storing the document to db, then you might have to deserialize it to list by your own code.

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.OTrackedList
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.OSerializableStream
import java.util.ArrayList
import collection.JavaConverters._

object Hoo{
  // To able to serialize/deserialize with OrientDB, you have to implement fromStream()/toStream()
  class Version(str:String) extends OSerializableStream{
    override def fromStream(stream:Array[Byte]):Version = {
      new Version(stream.map{_.toChar}.mkString(""))
    }
    override def toStream:Array[Byte] = {
      str.toArray.map{_.toByte}
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]){
    // Open DB
    val db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("local:/tmp/test")
    db.open("admin","admin")
    // Create Document
    val doc = new ODocument("Person")
    doc.field("versions",Array(new Version("3.1.4"),new Version("2.7.18")))
    // Save Document to DB
    doc.save

    // Query Doucument
    val result:ArrayList[ODocument] = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery[ODocument]("select * from Person"))
    val lst:OTrackedList[Version] = result.get(0).field("versions")
    // OTrackedList is subclass of ArrayList, so you can convert it with toSeq()
    println(lst.asScala.toSeq) // prints Buffer(Main$Version|3.1.4, Main$Version|2.7.18)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, now that I've tested further, it seems to me that as you evaluate lst.asScala.toSeq it fails since it contains `String`s. The deserialization method (`fromStream`) doesn't get called.

Comment: What I've found indicates that even Versions must be stored as ODocuments.